# How to store and search a dictionary in a trie

Tags: java, dictionary, trie

I need to create a trie in Java for my Boggle game. I have tried searching for this site for help before hand but only got answers for C or Python but nothing on Java.

Anyways to keep it short, I was wondering how one would go about storing a dictionary (so like a text file of words; around 100k words) into a trie. I've read up about the trie and found it hard to visualize code for it.

Specifically I'm looking for steps to follow when programming (so like what methods I should include and what they do).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've done this (in Qt), but it requires thought.

Comment: Are you doing the homework from Cousera's Algorithms class? If so, the videos have already explained in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [TrieST](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/52trie/TrieST.java.html)? I really suggest you do. Otherwise, I suggest reading [this](http://www.toptal.com/java/the-trie-a-neglected-data-structure) article. Maybe also [this](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/enrich/c16/tries.htm) one.